# Disk not ejected properly: Volume doesn't mount anymore

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount

I am using a WD Passport 4TB on a Macbook air, Catalina OSX.
When I accidentally remove the drive without ejecting it, it can't be mounted anymore and the Volume is greyed out (image below)

[image]

After this, I always have to input the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo pkill -f fsck
diskutil repairVolume disk2s2
```

This whole procedure takes more than an hour to complete. Despite the fact that I'm really trying to be careful, it still happens occasionally. It really drives me mad, as I'm losing so much time (I have all my files there). I never had such problem with Windows. Is there any solution to this, other than the one I'm using?

P.S. the drive is formated as ExFat. May it be the cause of the problem?